# Tablesorter how to remove selected rows from table

Tags: javascript, row, tablesorter

The example here shows how to append new rows to the tablesorter table. 
https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-add-rows.html
How would I remove selected rows from the table ?
I would plan to append a column with checkbox elements like below. But how would I trigger the removal and the deletion process, in a way that the table is updated ?

```
<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>Parker</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td class="discount">$9.99</td>
      <td>20%</td>
      <td>Jul 6, 2006 8:14 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Hood</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td class="discount">$19.99</td>
      <td>25%</td>
      <td>Dec 10, 2002 5:14 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Clark</td>
      <td>Kent</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td class="discount">$15.89</td>
      <td>44%</td>
      <td>Jan 12, 2003 11:14 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Almighty</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td class="discount">$153.19</td>
      <td>44%</td>
      <td>Jan 18, 2001 9:12 AM</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

At current I add new elements to table with:

```
var row = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>'+ano+'</td><td>'+aname+'</td><td>'+anumber.value+'</td><td>'+start+'</td><td>'+ende+'</td></tr>';
              $row = $(row),
              resort = true;
            $('#table1')
              .find('tbody').append($row)
              .trigger('addRows', [$row, resort]);
```

My problem is, in case I have added an invalid item to the table I need to have a possibility to remove this again.
@mottie,@marc Thank you for the support.
I have solved it now with this javascript code:

```
        function RemoveRow(row){

            var table = document.getElementById ("table");
            var count=1;
            var rowcount = table.rows.length;
              $('#table tr:has(td)').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
                count++;
                if ($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                    table.deleteRow(count);
                    count--;
                }
              });
            var resort = true;
            $("#table1").trigger("update", [resort]);
        }
```

This code above does what I need, execpt I am not sure if this to cumbersome coded.

Comment: If your `<tr>` has an ID, and the associated checkbox references the ID of the row, then it becomes very straightforward.  I suggest you move toward that.

Comment: @Marc My problem is that this is not a standard html table but a tablesorter table. I do not know enough about the internal structure.

Comment: But you know how to add a row, which is what you provided an example of. That's just HTML.  I.e., that IS the structure.

Comment: Instead of using `addRows`, use [`update`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#update) to update tablesorter's internal cache after adding or removing rows.

Comment: I have updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it this way:

```
 function RemoveRow(row){

            var table = document.getElementById ("table");
            var count=1;
            var rowcount = table.rows.length;
              $('#table tr:has(td)').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
                count++;
                if ($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                    table.deleteRow(count);
                    count--;
                }
              });
            var resort = true;
            $("#table1").trigger("update", [resort]);
        }
```